# How to substitute a formula?

Tags: math-mode

I have this formula for *x*:

```
x = \frac{ P_k\zeta_{k+1} + P_{k-1} }{Q_k\zeta_{k+1}+Q_{k-1} }
```

and I want to substitute it into a quadratic:

*ax*<sup>2</sup> + *bx* + *c* = 0

Is there a way to have some sort of global definition for my formula so I don't have to copy and paste it and have ugly looking code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yes, it's trivially possible with a `\newcommand`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\eks}{\frac{ P_k\zeta_{k+1} + P_{k-1} }{Q_k\zeta_{k+1}+Q_{k-1} }}

\begin{document}

\[
  a\left(\eks\right)^{2} + b\left(\eks\right) + c = 0
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I'm not sure doing it like that every time would make your life any easier. For one thing, you'd have to keep coming up with command names and you'd quickly lose track of which one was which.