# How to automate substitution in equations

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

How can I automate equation substitutions in LaTeX?
I understand that I can create a `\newcommand`, as per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337874/13134), but that solution seems not scalable to a longer document.

My MWE is below. I was wondering if there is an automatic method that can refer to the part after the `=` sign of an equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Two basic equations:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:f}
    F_n = F \cdot \sin(\theta)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:theta}
    \theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a} \right)
\end{equation}
Substitute~\ref{eq:theta} into~\ref{eq:f} to obtain equation~\ref{eq:full}:
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:full}
    F_n = F \cdot sin\left( \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a} \right)\right)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

For the full equation I would like to do something along the lines of below pseudocode:

```
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:full}
    F_n = F \cdot sin\left( \eqref{eq:theta} \right)\right)
\end{equation}
```

Is this possible, without defining each equation separately with `\newcommand`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not the syntax proposed by the OP, I think it could work for his application.

Here I introduce

```
\DefineTerm{<\name>}{<compact representation>}{<expanded representation>}
```

to allow the use of `\name` and `\name*` to achieve either the compacted or expanded representation so defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\DefineTerm[3]{\gdef#1{\@ifstar{#3}{#2}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\DefineTerm\Xtheta{\theta}{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a} \right)}
\begin{equation}
    F_n = F \cdot \sin(\Xtheta)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \Xtheta = \Xtheta*
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:full}
    F_n = F \cdot \sin\left( \Xtheta*\right)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]